# What's the fastest idiomatic way to mutate multiple struct fields at the same time?

Tags: struct, event-handling, rust, mio

Many libraries allow you to define a type which implements a given `trait` to be used as a callback handler. This requires you to lump all of the data you'll need to handle the event together in a single data type, which complicates borrows.

For instance, [`mio`](https://github.com/carllerche/mio) allows you to implement [`Handler`](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/trait.Handler.html) and provide your struct when you [run the `EventLoop`](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/master/mio/struct.EventLoop.html#method.run). Consider an example with these trivialized data types:

```
struct A {
  pub b: Option<B>
};

struct B;

struct MyHandlerType {
  pub map: BTreeMap<Token, A>,
  pub pool: Pool<B>
}
```

Your handler has a map from `Token` to items of type `A`. Each item of type `A` may or may not already have an associated value of type `B`. In the handler, you want to look up the `A` value for a given `Token` and, if it doesn't already have a `B` value, get one out of the handler's `Pool<B>`.

```
impl Handler for MyHandlerType {
    fn ready(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<MyHandlerType>, 
             token: Token, events: EventSet) {
       let a : &mut A = self.map.get_mut(token).unwrap();
       let b : B = a.b.take().or_else(|| self.pool.new()).unwrap();
       // Continue working with `a` and `b`
       // ...
    }
}
```

In this arrangement, even though it's intuitively possible to see that `self.map` and `self.pool` are distinct entities, the borrow checker complains that `self` is already borrowed (via `self.map`) when we go to access `self.pool`.

One possible approach to this would be to wrap each field in `MyHandlerType` in `Option<>`. Then, at the start of the method call, `take()` those values out of `self` and restore them at the end of the call:

```
struct MyHandlerType {
  // Wrap these fields in `Option`
  pub map: Option<BTreeMap<Token, A>>,
  pub pool: Option<Pool<B>>
}
// ...

fn ready(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<MyHandlerType>, 
         token: Token, events: EventSet) {
  // Move these values out of `self`
  let map = self.map.take().unwrap();
  let pool = self.pool.take().unwrap();

  let a : &mut A = self.map.get_mut(token).unwrap();
  let b : B = a.b.take().or_else(|| self.pool.new()).unwrap();
  // Continue working with `a` and `b`
  // ...

  // Restore these values to `self`
  self.map = Some(map);
  self.pool = Some(pool);
}
```

This works but feels a bit kluge-y. It also introduces the overhead of moving values in and out of `self` for each method call.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get simultaneous mutable references to different parts of the struct, use destructuring. Example [here](http://is.gd/VKuP6J).

```rust
struct Pair {
    x: Vec<u32>,
    y: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Pair {
    fn test(&mut self) -> usize {
        let Pair{ ref mut x, ref mut y } = *self;
        // Both references coexist now
        return x.len() + y.len();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut nums = Pair {
        x: vec![1, 2, 3],
        y: vec![4, 5, 6, 7],
    };
    println!("{}", nums.test());
}
```

Comment: !!! Thank you! I knew about destructuring but had no idea you could use it to get simultaneous mutable references. This was a huge help!